# My array is not empty but array.length returns 0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

This is a really strange issue I've been trying to debug today;
When the component mounts I'm getting the notifications to display them like this

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        notifications: this.props.notifications,
      }
    );
  }
```

And then I tried to console log the notifications by adding this

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        notifications: this.props.notifications,
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.notifications);
        console.log(this.state.notifications.length);
      }
    );
  }
```

And what I get is this!

first console.log()

```
[]
0: {title: "Success", text: "You have successfully created a new game!", destination: {…}, type: "GameCreated"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

second console.log()

```
0
```

Shouldn't the array length be 1 instead of 0? I do have an element in that array.
Also when I try to get the first value to that array it returns undefined.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and help out!

Comment: `useState` is async in nature. So if you try to access it before it sets the state, it is gonna give error

Comment: Please edit your question by replacing the screenshot with text (copy & paste).  Not only do links die, but it poses problems for the visually impaired.

Comment: @RamblinRose i updated it :) sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you output an object with `console.log` its state may evolve and you are not necessarily seeing the state of this object at the time `console.log` was called but only at the time it was expanded in the console view. Which is not the case with primitives. 
Most probable scenario: when calling console.log the array was empty, with a length of 0. When you expand the Array log in the console view you will see it populated even if it was not at the time it was logged.

Comment: to verify this, you can change the line to `console.log([ ...this.state.notifications ])`, so that the logged object will not be mutated before you're able to check it

Comment: thats actually very true, i did change my console log with what you mentioned and it returns an empty array as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did the same test and it works correctly on my computer, it logs length as 1. 
Maybe there is something else in your code that is causing a side effect

Answer (score 0):

In your browser, `console.log` is working as an async function.

Check this question: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440)

To avoid this, you can use `JOSN.parse( JSON.stringify(MutableData) )` like below;

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        notifications: this.props.notifications,
      },
      () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.notifications)));
        console.log(this.state.notifications.length);
      }
    );
  }
```